# How to guess full file name, having only first 2 letters

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a directory full of files, which names are prefixed with sequential, unique number - like so:

```
/01 - Gruppe #1 - Potatisvalsen.mp3
/02 - Gruppe #1 - Wondrous Love & Hell Broke Loose in Georgia.mp3
```

Those are accessible at `http://mysite/01 - Gruppe #1 - Potatisvalsen.mp3` etc.

I would like to rewrite calls like `http://mysite/01.mp3` to the correct full URL as above.

I have tried the "obvious":

```
RewriteRule ^/(\d+)*\.mp3$ ./$1(.*)\.mp3
```

But that probably just shows my ignorance :)

Is this possible using `mod_rewrite`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**mod_rewrite cannot do this shell expansion**. You will be better off forwarding these requests to a PHP script and load the actual file there.

**Step 1: Forward to PHP**

```
RewriteRule ^\d{2}\.mp3$ fileloader.php?f=$0 [L,QSA,NC]
```

**Step 2: Inside `fileloader.php`**

1. Load a list of files from current directory into an associative array
2. Perform a lookup on those filename using `$_GET['f']`
3. Serve the found file